# Errors thrown when creating new react-native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I just downloaded node, and I am learning how to start a react native app. I am using expo to start the app, on expo's website it says this -
After installing Node.js, you can use npx to create a new app.

```
npx create-expo-app --template
```

I made a folder for my app, and I opened a new terminal in vscode, when I run that line of code it gives me a bunch of erros:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\umarm\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\umarm\AppData\Roaming\npm' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\umarm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-30T03_02_47_954Z-debug-0.log       
PS C:\Users\umarm\OneDrive\Desktop\react_native_jobs>
```

How do I fix this?
Also if anyone knows any good recources to learn how to use react/react native within a weekend with minimal html/css/javascript experience please let me know!

I mentioned everything above, but also I am a beginner so please explain it like your explaining it to a 5 year old!

Comment: You could potentially try to reinstall node, since it looks like it can't find node at all. `npm install -g npm` This command will reinstall npm globally on your computer rather than just locally on a user. Also can you check `C:\Users\umarm\AppData\Roaming\npm` to see if npm even exists there. (I assume not since it can't find it)

Comment: try to install node again